# Selenium / PhantomJS can't get url - random failure

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm using python with `Selenium` and `phantomJS` to crawl a website.
`Beautifulsoup` to parse some html.
 
Everything works fine but I get random failure where the script is blocked in the while loop below that launch the webdriver and get the url content.

```
while (htmlContent is None) :
    try:
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        driver.get(url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source , 'html.parser')
        htmlContent = soup.find("table", class_="desc-item")
        driver.close()
    except:
```

- I try again (restart the python script) on this particular url
  where the script is failing --> it's working.
- If I put a timeout exception, the script is continuing correctly to scrape other urls but failed randomly on other urls.

I'm running out of ideas - any suggestions ? 
Thx !

Comment: Remove the try/except block, let it fail and post the exception you see. Thanks.

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(20) #Use it only one time, the second is not necesary.
Catch exception with --> except Exception as e: and print(str(e))